# JavaScript: Why I get `undefined` when I use an assignment with destructuring?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript, Google Chrome

This is my code example. Why I get the `undefined` values?

```js
let foo = {name: 'Bob', age: 24};
let {name, age} = foo;

console.log(name); // 'Bob'
console.log(age); // 24

foo = {color: 'red', result: true};
({name, age} = foo);

console.log(name); // "undefined" instead of 'red'
console.log(age); // undefined instead of true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), destructuring assignment for structures is based on property names. For your second assignment, since your object doesn't have properties `name` and `age`, those variables become undefined.

If you want to rename properties when assigning to variables, you can use the following syntax:

```
foo = {color: 'red', result: true};
({color: name, result: age} = foo);
```

That will assign the `color` property of `foo` to the variable `name` and the `result` property to `age`.

Answer (score 4):

Destructuring the way you did it will match on the keys, not position (you can't really depend on the key order in objects).

```
const {foo} = {foo: "bar"}
```

is the equivalent of saying

```
const foo = ({foo: "bar"}).foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how the code is transpiled using babel and it becomes really clear what is happening. 
[Using the babel console](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAZg9jEF4IG8B2BDAtiAXBA5AEIwBG-ANBOgOa4QBMALAL4DcAUKJGliJTSGaJocDuwDGMVAGcYoAHTAY1ABQZsASlYQA9DoLEyEqbIVLVArbv1N27WPCTJJSgE558rkABMKEL9IArsBgeGCugYIcKjzY_LRCSA5adpIyciCKymq8VnoQAESBqN4gUACWqD4FEJXSYCDo3hAwUARevsbpZtmW2vnFpRVVzXUNTS1t4ZFAA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0)

```
'use strict';

var foo = { name: 'Bob', age: 24 };
var _foo = foo,
    name = _foo.name,
    age = _foo.age;


console.log(name); // 'Bob'
console.log(age); // 24

foo = { color: 'red', result: true };
var _foo2 = foo;
name = _foo2.name;
age = _foo2.age;


console.log(name); // "undefined" instead of 'red'
console.log(age); // undefined instead of true
```